# I am trying to understand the difference between parallel and sequential code using MPI library with C++ language

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, embedded-linux

This is the code "expl.cpp":

```c
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"
using namespace std;
int main (int argc,char **argv)
{   
cout << "this line of code is executed in sequential mode " << endl ;
MPI::Init();
cout << "hello MPI world!" << endl ;
MPI::Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

After compiling the code above with

```sh
mpicc -o expl expl.cpp
```

and executing the binary file with this command

```sh
mpirun -np 4 ./expl
```

my *expected* output was :

```
this line of code is executed in sequential mode
hello MPI world!
hello MPI world!
hello MPI world!
hello MPI world!
```

but I get this output :

```
this line of code is executed in sequential mode
this line of code is executed in sequential mode
this line of code is executed in sequential mode
this line of code is executed in sequential mode
hello MPI world!
hello MPI world!
hello MPI world!
hello MPI world!
```

I'm looking for a simple clarification.

Comment: The MPI standard does not specify what happens before `MPI_Init()` and `MPI_Finalize()`. Most MPI implementations choose to spawn all the tasks (that's why you end up having multiple "sequential mode" lines), but it would be perfectly valid to start a single MPI task, and then `fork()` at `MPI_Init()` so you would have only one "sequential mode" line. If you wand to write portable code, it is safer/better not do do anything before `MPI_Init()` and `MPI_Finalize()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [doc](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man1/mpirun.1.php) you it says

> This will run X copies of  in your current run-time environment

Which is exactly what happens.

Comment: if all the code will be executed in parallel by the `mpirun` command, then what is the use of the `MPI::Init();` and `MPI::Finalize();` in this example?

Comment: Reading the docs for those, says that they initialize and destroys the MPI environment. what you are really looking for must be some use of threads and not invoke the same program multiple times.